# Simple one? Passing a var to PHP page from Chrome extension page?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I am trying to pass a var to a PHP page and then open it in a new tab in Chrome extension.

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="open PHP" onClick="OnClickbtn()">
```

JavaScript:

```
function OnClickbtn()
{
 window.location.href = "http://localhost/Chrome/Test.php?var=1234";
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$var=$_GET['var'];

echo "Link is: ";
echo $var;

?>
```

Now...
the thing is that I cannot send the var to the PHP
and even if I do, How would I open it in Chrome new TAB from the Chrome extension?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a listener event to the chrome extension. Are you able to give more information on your chrome extension?

Comment: Its a simple extension, with one button that send the current URL to the PHP Server, then the server open the URL in a different tab inside an iframe. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried using `chrome.tabs.create(object createProperties, function callback)`?
You will need to declare the "tabs" permission in the extension manifest.

Take a look [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-create)

Edit:
As i said in comments:

> Loading the URL like you are doing should work, maybe you are having
>   problems with long urls that have special characters like # or & (ie:
>   a google search), that's because you have to escape the url with
>   `encodeURIComponent(url)` or `escape(url)`

Working example (works in my test at least):
`window.location.href = 'http://localhost/test.php?var=' + encodeURIComponent('https://www.google.com.ar/#hl=es-419&q=urlencode+javascript')`

Comment: thanks. i will look into it. do u have an idea for sending the parameter to the php server? thanks!

Comment: Loading the URL like you are doing should work, maybe you are having problems with long urls that have special characters like # or & (ie: a google search), that's because you have to escape the url with `encodeURIComponent(url)` or `escape(url)`